# Minipage or parbox doesn't work in bcbar label (bchart package)

Tags: minipage

The code below works very well on an `article` document. But, when I put it on a chapter of a `book` document class, it doesn't work. The problem is the `minipage` use. The `book` class document doesn't accept the `minipage` use for configuring the `bcbar`. Like this:

```
label=\begin{minipage}{5cm}Texto\\continuaçao do texto\end{minipage}.
```

Maybe you know why?
If not, you can propose another way for do it? I need to work on `bcbar` to fit bigger labels.

```
\begin{grafico}
   \caption{Tese grafico da tese}
   \centering
   \begin{bchart}[step=2,max=10, unit=\%, scale=0.7]
              \bcbar[label=grupo 1]{3.4}
                  \medskip
              \bcbar[label={\footnotesize Produzo o material didático que utilizo (sou autor[a] do material)}]{5.6}
                  \medskip
              \bcbar[label=\begin{minipage}{5cm}Texto\\continuaçao do texto\end{minipage}]{7.2}
                  \bigskip
              \bcbar{9.9}
          \end{bchart}
   \label{tab:box1}
\end{grafico}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

The following works without error using `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bchart}

\begin{document}

\chapter{zzz}
\begin{figure}
   \caption{Tese grafico da tese}
   \centering
   \begin{bchart}[step=2,max=10, unit=\%, scale=0.7]
              \bcbar[label=grupo 1]{3.4}
                  \medskip
              \bcbar[label={\footnotesize Produzo o material didático que utilizo (sou autor[a] do material)}]{5.6}
                  \medskip
              \bcbar[label=\begin{minipage}{5cm}Texto\\continuaçao do texto\end{minipage}]{7.2}
                  \bigskip
              \bcbar{9.9}
          \end{bchart}
   \label{tab:box1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```